# Is it possible to loop through objects inside an object using for loops?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through one of my objects and get the objects inside that object.

In this example, I'm trying to loop through the `items` in the `orderCart` to get the `qty` and `price`

```
{ _id: 591327ea6325162512438858,
   orderCart: 
   { totalPrice: 66.95,
     totalQty: 5,
     items: 
      { '5900e2e1e2e75276ca68e10c': { item: [Object], qty: 2, price: 25.98 },
        '5900d8fde2e75276ca68e107': { item: [Object], qty: 2, price: 25.98 },
        '58fff1d322f00e71fdbfe422': { item: [Object], qty: 2, price: 25.98 }
      } 
   },
   orderEmail: 'email@gmail.com',
   orderFullName: 'John Doe'
}
```

Is it possible to do this with a for loop/forEach or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for...in` or you can iterate over `Object.keys()`

```js
var myObj = {
  _id: "591327ea6325162512438858",
  orderCart: {
    totalPrice: 66.95,
    totalQty: 5,
    items: {
      '5900e2e1e2e75276ca68e10c': {
        item: [Object],
        qty: 2,
        price: 25.98
      },
      '5900d8fde2e75276ca68e107': {
        item: [Object],
        qty: 2,
        price: 25.98
      },
      '58fff1d322f00e71fdbfe422': {
        item: [Object],
        qty: 2,
        price: 25.98
      }
    }
  },
  orderEmail: 'email@gmail.com',
  orderFullName: 'John Doe'
};

console.log("---- for...in ----");
for (var key in myObj.orderCart.items) {
  if (myObj.orderCart.items.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var obj = myObj.orderCart.items[key];
    console.log(obj.qty, obj.price);
  }
}
console.log("---- Object.keys() ----");
Object.keys(myObj.orderCart.items).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = myObj.orderCart.items[key];
  console.log(obj.qty, obj.price);
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly. This is gonna save me a lot of code and loops.

Comment: Keep in mind that `for..in` also iterates over any properties the object may have inherited through the prototype chain. That's why it's strongly discouraged to do anything with `Object.prototype` but because of the chance that someone may have done that it's a good idea to check with `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` when iterating an object with `for..in`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Ahh yes, I can't believe I forgot about that. I will update my post. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can get an array of the keys of your object with Object.keys(items). Then you can loop over this array of keys and use them to look at each key/value pair and check out qty and price.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in